# build scipy error cythonize failed

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I'm trying to build scipy and I get a RuntimeError:

```
$sudo python setup.py build
Processing scipy/cluster/_vq_rewrite.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/cythonize.py", line 172, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/cythonize.py", line 168, in main
    find_process_files(root_dir)
  File "tools/cythonize.py", line 160, in find_process_files
    process(cur_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
  File "tools/cythonize.py", line 137, in process
    processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
  File "tools/cythonize.py", line 66, in process_pyx
    raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed')
OSError: Cython needs to be installed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 209, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 202, in setup_package
    generate_cython()
  File "setup.py", line 147, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
```

What are the ways to provide cython to remedy this error?

Answer (score 88):

Python setuptools solved the problem.

http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/install.html
`easy_install cython` or `pip install cython`

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to include that in the documentation of scipy?

Comment: or as an automatic dependency?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have Cython installed then use: `pip install Cython`.
However, if you do have an old version of Cython installed like me then this is what solved it for me: `pip install --upgrade Cython`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem occurred due to incompatible python + pandas versions due to incorrect environment configurations despite using Anaconda. Installing Cython via pip worked too, but that wasn't the *real* solution.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `Cython` which did not solve the problem. I solved it by upgrading my pip: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`.