# Unable to install Scipy using pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

I use the 'pip install scipy' command in the cmd, but get this error at the end. How do I fix it?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Spencer>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.17.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
Running from numpy source directory.
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\setup.py:327: UserWarning:
Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info
.py:1640: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info
.py:1649: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info
.py:1652: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info
.py:1542: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info
.py:1553: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-3pkkpt\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info
.py:1556: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-i4x0vy\scipy\setup.py", line 265, in <modu
le>
    setup_package()
  File "c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-i4x0vy\scipy\setup.py", line 262, in setup
_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 629, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 659, in install_
item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 842, in install_
eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1070, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1058, in run_set
up
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in       c:\users\spencer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-i4x0vy\scipy\
```

EDIT: added the entire error
The post has too much code and won't let me post, please ignore these next could of sentences as it is just to fill the required amount before I can post this.

Comment: updated the comment so that it has the entire error

Comment: Your problem is with the lack of underlying scientific libraries and according to [this](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html) page they are a pain to build on Windows. Scipy needs a [whole stack](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) of packages to work properly and the recommended solution is to use precompiled packages as in the answer by @MattDMo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For modules on Windows that require compilation, just use Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. You can download `scipy` [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), but as indicated you'll need to also install the MKL version of [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

Once you have downloaded the `.whl` files, simply install them with

```
pip install -U wheel_file_name.whl
```

The `-U` is for upgrade, in case you have a previous version installed already.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between using .whl files and installing directly from pip ? Asking because I spent almost an hour trying to install through pip (I mean PyPi package) but never got it to work. Was almost going to install Anaconda do deal with this but saw your comment and got scipy installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

download installer for your version of python from this website: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases

There are a lot of files to download from the website but e.g. for python 2.7, the right installer is named scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe 
After downloading the file, you can easily install Scipy by a few clicks.

Comment: Except that the latest version of scipy is 0.17.0, and there is no executable installer for it on that page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to install cython. I was hitting the same error and "sudo pip install cython" solved the issue. See here [build scipy error cythonize failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175135/build-scipy-error-cythonize-failed)

Answer (score 0):

In the errors it says: "Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27"